Ubuntu 20.04 で docker をインストールしたい
環境：
ubuntu@user:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

下記のサイトを参考にしました。
ubuntu 20.04.1 上でプロキシ環境でdocker を利用する
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo apt update -y
Hit:1 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                            
Hit:3 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:4 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                    
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

ubuntu@user:~$ sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

下記のエラーが出されます。
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo apt install -y docker.io docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker.io : Depends: containerd (>= 1.2.6-0ubuntu1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Ununtuの版数が違うけれどもこちらの記事が参考になるのでは？ docker を ubuntu 18.04 にインストールしようとしたら怒られた あるいはこちらの方が合っているかもしれませんが。docker.io : Depends: containerd (>= 1.2.6-0ubuntu1~)

ありがとうございます。
以下の対処法で解決できました。
https://qiita.com/ItsukiN32/items/8f5cd80b64912d78fb43
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo apt install -y docker.io docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-compose is already the newest version (1.25.0-1).
docker.io is already the newest version (24.0.7-0ubuntu2~20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


参照した記事で行った対策のキモは、事前に sudo apt-get remove containerd.io で競合するパッケージを削除した部分かと思うので、ここを回答にも含めるべきではないかと思います。
